# How to monitor/limit data usage on enterprise network

Tags: networking, download, network-programming, server, monitoring

I recently joined a startup as the network admin and one of the most essential tasks i was asked to do was to find a way to monitor the total and individual usage of data by each device in our environment and auto-generate reports every week.
However, I have contacted many of my colleagues and even they are confused with this requirement. I would be very much obliged if you guys could help me out with this tricky situation.

My network infrastructure is like this

3x WAN => Load Balancer => Switch => Second Switch (More Ubuntu PC) + PC Devices (Ubuntu mainly) + Router (=>Phones + Laptops)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to setup a mirroring port in your first switch. Then by connecting a pc with a network monitoring software installed to this mirroring port.

Comment: Any recommendations regarding the choice to be used for an SMB network with less than 50 pcs connected?

Comment: Also, will the mirroring interface monitor the inbound local network traffic alongside the external WAN network traffic?